# Mysql derived table

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have a mysql table name table with fields

- rank
- date
- id

The values are like:

```
10, 2012-01-01, 3
9,  2012-01-04, 3
5,  2012-01-07, 3
3,  2012-01-10, 3
10, 2012-01-01, 4 
6,  2012-01-04, 4 
7,  2012-01-07, 4
```

In a single sql, how can i get both last and first values sorted by date grouped by id?

I know how to get first one or last one

```
SELECT rank, id FROM 
  (SELECT rank, id FROM table ORDER BY date DESC) s GROUP BY id;
```

I would like that the fields returned to be somethink like: lastrank, firstrank and id.

Thank you

Comment: when you say lastrank/firstrank is that based on rank value or date value?

Comment: min(rank) and max(rank) are not always the first and last row. The rows are sorted by date, not rank. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id,
  max(if(MyOrder = 1, rank, null)) as FirstRank,
  max(if(MyOrder = 2, rank, null)) as LastRank
from (
    select t1.id, t1.rank, 1 MyOrder from t t1
    left join t t2 on
    t1.id = t2.id and t1.date > t2.date
    where t2.date is null
    union
    select t1.id, t1.rank, 2 from t t1
    left join t t2 on
    t1.id = t2.id and t1.date < t2.date
    where t2.date is null
) s
group by id
```

The result of this query taking your sampla data as input is:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | FIRSTRANK | LASTRANK |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  3 |        10 |        3 |
|  4 |        10 |        7 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: min(rank) and max(rank) are not always the first and last row. The rows are sorted by date, not rank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure that I understand your question, but I'm going to try to answer anyway.

```
SELECT min(rank), max(rank), id
  FROM table
  ORDER BY date DESC
  GROUP BY id;
```

When grouping, you can use aggregate functions on the results to get specific samples from the groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  IF(t1.date = t2.min_date, 'FIRSTRANK', 'LASTRANK') rank_type
FROM table_rank t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(date) max_date, MIN(date) min_date FROM table_rank GROUP BY id
    ) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND (t1.date = t2.min_date OR t1.date = t2.max_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Involve GROUP_CONCAT(rank ORDER BY date), and use SUBSTRING_INDEX.